# Using I-phone 8 while flying over Pacific Ocean

Tags: usa, air-travel, cellphones

I will be flying from America to Japan, then the Philippines next week. Will my I-phone 8 work out over the Pacific Ocean? Or just turn it off to save roaming charges?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Can you be more specific as to what you mean by "work,"  and what airline(s) you will be flying? You probably won't be able to make voice calls, you probably will be able to buy Internet access over WiFi, and you certainly should be able to use it offline.

Comment: Are you asking whether your phone will literally work while you're on the plane, "over the Pacific Ocean"?  Or are you asking whether your phone will work when you're on the ground in Japan and the Philippines?

Answer (score 4):

Most air carriers prohibit the use of cell-based communications while in flight. A few carriers provide cell connectivity.

Many aircraft, however, contain wi-fi routers, which allow wi-fi connectivity while the airplane is in the air. Passengers usually must pay for this connection, although connections to the airline's own web page (perhaps including some entertainment streaming) may be provided without charge.

Certain types of communication, such a voice calls of any type, are still prohibited by almost all carriers.

Source: a lot of flying.

Comment: There has for at least 10 years or so been several air lines allowing mobile phone voice calls during flight. Some airlines have dropped their services again, since many passengers find it annonying.

Comment: Yes, there was a lot of consumer push-back. I'm not aware of any airlines now permitting voice calls.

Comment: It is not at all uncommon on European airlines. I haven't flown on many different airlines, but at least Virgin Atlantic and SAS allow voice calls on some of their flights. I wouldn't be surprised if it is offered on many Asian airlines as well.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Fair enough. I've amended the answer.

Comment: Your technical explanation is still incorrect. It doesn't matter if there are cell towers under your route. The air lines allowing voice calls, are operating their own cell phone network onboard the plane, to which your phone will connect.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I'm aware of wifi connectivity in airplanes, but not connectivity using cellular tech. Can you point me to a report of that tech?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Further searching revealed at least one tech company providing in-flight cell connectivity technology for air carriers. I've amended the answer.

Comment: What kind of 'report' are you looking for, which you can't find using Google? The airlines are simply operating their own cell onboard the aircraft. There is nothing magic about that. Similar services have been provided on ships for several decades and after the lifting of official restrictions on cell phone usage in aircrafts, many airlines have started using the same concept as well.